# Setting the working directory

Tags: launcher

I want to create a quick launch icon for MATLAB, but it won't start if the working directory is not the same as the directory where the executable is. Can I specify the working directory in the 'Custom Application Launcher'?

[image: Custom launcher]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the working directory natively, but for some reason it's not supported in the user interface. The underlying .desktop file itself supports a `Path` key for "the working directory to run the program in" (see the [spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.2.html#key-path)) as long as your launcher is an "Application" type.

So just open the .desktop file in a text editor (if you're having trouble finding it, you can create the launcher on your desktop and find it in `~/Desktop`, then move it later), and add a line at the end that says `Path=YOUR_PATH`.

Comment: Amazing. I can't believe Gnome is missing this in the UI. Any idea if it's visible in latest gnome versions?

Comment: I don't think it's been added, and in fact I think recent versions of gnome dropped the "Create Application Launcher" option. I recommend https://github.com/MicahCarrick/desktop-entry-editor as a replacement.

Answer (score 8):

Change the *Command* to this (substituting the correct paths of course):

```
bash -c "cd /path/to/directory && /path/to/directory/executable"
```

Comment: This sort of worked, but only after I set Type to 'Application in Terminal'. For some reason it doesn't work if it's just Application.

Comment: @satuon Strange, maybe that's a MATLAB specific thing.

Comment: @satuon: could you try using `/bin/sh` instead of `sh`? Perhaps it works then

Comment: @sashoalm (better late than never) you need to specify the option -desktop if you dont want to run it from terminal.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html