# Creating a .desktop for Unigine Heaven 4.0

Tags: command-line, .desktop

I'm trying to create an application launcher for a program (unigine heaven), I've created a .desktop file which looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Unigine Heaven 4.0
Type=Application
Icon=heaven-icon.png
Exec=/home/**redacted**/Unigine_Heaven-4.0/heaven
Terminal=true
```

I've made the file executable, and tried to run it, and nothing happens. If i go into terminal inside `/home/**redacted**/Unigine_Heaven-4.0/` and run `./heaven`, everything works as it should, I just can't get that terminal command to work within a .desktop file. Any ideas?

Edit: formatting for clarity

Comment: Can you try this `Exec=sh -c "cd /home/**redacted**/Unigine_Heaven-4.0;  ./heaven"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we examine the executable script `heaven` we shall see the paths inside are relative:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cd ./bin
ARCH=$(uname -m)
if [ "$ARCH" == x86_64 ]; then
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./x64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    ./browser_x64 -config ../data/launcher/launcher.xml
else
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./x86:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    ./browser_x86 -config ../data/launcher/launcher.xml
fi
```

So the solution is to add working directory (`Path` key) to the launcher (the `.desktop` file):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Unigine Heaven 4.0
Type=Application
Icon=heaven-icon.png
Path=/home/<user>/Unigine_Heaven-4.0
Exec=/home/<user>/Unigine_Heaven-4.0/heaven
Terminal=false
```

- Replace `/home/<user>/Unigine_Heaven-4.0` with the actual path in use.
- Please note also this change: `Terminal=false`.
- The [solution provided by @Sans](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967458/creating-a-desktop-for-unigine-heaven-4-0#comment1549120_967458) also works:

  ```
  Exec=sh -c "cd /home/<user>/Unigine_Heaven-4.0/heaven; ./heaven"
  ```

---

References:

- [Setting the working directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50085/setting-the-working-directory)
- [Recognized desktop entry keys](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)